# How to find the highest number in all textboxes

Tags: vb.net

I'm close to finishing a small program that i started, but got stuck with the last part. And I'm just starting to learn programming, so might be a stupid question.

How can i get the text box with the highest number out of 16 boxes,each having its own number, but at the same time keep track of which one still has the highest number every second? Quite confused about the updating it every second part.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Please show your current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code suggestion

```
 Private Sub findTopTextBox()

        Dim topValue As Integer
        Dim topTextBox As TextBox
        For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls 'all the controls on your form
            If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
                Dim thisValue As Integer
                If Integer.TryParse(DirectCast(ctrl, TextBox).Text, thisValue) Then
                    If thisValue > topValue Then
                        topValue = thisValue
                        topTextBox = DirectCast(ctrl, TextBox)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next

        Debug.Print(String.Concat(topTextBox.Name, " has the top value at: ", topValue))

    End Sub
```

In order to test it each second, you'll need to add a Timer and call this method repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to check every second only  check when a change was made in one of those textboxes
You could handle all your textboxes `LostFocus` event (using the same method to handle them all) ; get it's text, verify it's a number and if it's greater than the current max update it (along with it's "location" : the textbox control)
That way you always know which one is the greatest

Something along this should do it (typed directly here so not tested) :

```
Dim maxNumber As Integer, maxTextBox As TextBox

Sub TextBoxes_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles textbox1.LostFocus, textbox2.LostFocus ' ... for all textboxes
    Dim tbSender = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    Dim number As Integer

    ' Should we update maxTextBox if number = maxNumber ? (if yes change the > to >=)
    If Integer.TryParse(tbSender.Text, number) AndAlso number > maxNumber Then
        maxNumber = number
        maxTexBox = tbSender
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't consider `LostFocus` as it assumes the control ever received Focus. Same reasoning for not considering `TextChanged` or `KeyPress`. However, not saying anything wrong with your solution, just explaining why I didn't go that route.

Comment: @Mort how can the text could be changed without the control getting focused in the first place ?

Comment: I suppose the text values could be populated from another method, or calculation, or directly from a database?